# Artifactory oss install with Docker

Tags: docker, artifactory

I'm trying to install `Artifactory oss` using `docker`.

I'm running `ubuntu 18.04` and `docker 19.03.8`

I followed the JFrog installation guide https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation

I did all the steps.  Except that `chown -R 1030:1030 $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var` must be run with sudo.

The container start.  But when I'm going to http://myhost:8082/ui/ I only see a page with the JFrog logo displaying with a zoomin/zoomout effect.

I the logs I see

```
################################################################
###   All services started successfully in 116.053 seconds   ###
################################################################
2020-03-26T07:27:05.070Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8046
2020-03-26T07:27:05.070Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8049
2020-03-26T07:27:05.071Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on :8082
2020-03-26T07:27:05.109Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [alConfigurationServiceBase:182] [c-default-executor-1] - Loading configuration from db finished successfully
2020-03-26T07:27:07.104Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on :8082
2020-03-26T07:27:07.105Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8046
2020-03-26T07:27:07.105Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [                ] [server_configuration.go:61    ] [main                ] - Server configuration reloaded on localhost:8049
2020-03-26T07:27:10.084Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [6ec6165e7fec2711] [ternal_topology_verifier.go:92] [main                ] - failed pinging external node 'f461d2eebfe3' at address 'http://172.17.0.2:8082': Get http://172.17.0.2:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping: context deadline exceeded
```

The last line appears when I request the url in the browser.

What can I do ?

Edit:

I also tried with `docker-compose` also following the `jfrog guide`.

First run : artifactory is not starting !

After editing the `.jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml` and chaning the `127.0.0.1` by my `host name` followed again with the `config.sh` artifactory is starting.

But same problem when accessing http://myhost:8082/ui/

I don't understand what's happening and why it is not working following the jfrog guides...

Comment: Can you share the command you used to run the docker container?

Comment: Few things will help us get to the bottom of this:
1. Can you look at the console.log file in `$JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/log` folder and let me know if you see any exception. 
2. Can you run on the box running artifactory : `curl localhost:8046/router/api/v1/system/health`  and send the response?

Comment: @Eldad Assis
docker run --name artifactory -v $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest

Comment: @Prasanna Raghavendra  The only thing I see is 
`2020-03-26T10:21:24.889Z [jfrou] [WARN ] [346684fe2765928 ] [ternal_topology_verifier.go:92] [main                ] - failed pinging external node '1d4cecd7d7c9' at address 'http://172.17.0.2:8082': Get http://172.17.0.2:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping: context deadline exceeded`in `router-service.log`
Howerver if I do `curl http://172.17.0.2:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping` I receive `OK`

Comment: have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out to be that my proxy settings are blocking the http client from contacting the local endpoint.
I updated docker-compose.yml to include **no_proxy** and **noproxy** environment variables and Artifactory runs without any complaint.

```
services:
  artifactory:
    environment:
      - http_proxy=*********
      - https_proxy=*********
      - no_proxy=*********
      - noproxy=172.16.0.0/12
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was quite simple : try another browser !

With Edge it's not working.
With Firefox it's working ....